# I need to write a function to print out a week of a given month, with the arguments week number, start day and days in the month (Python)

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, calendar

Given a week number, (1st, 2nd, …), the day on which the 1st of the month falls (1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, …), and the number of days in the month: return a string consisting of the day of the month for each day in that week, starting with Monday and ending with Sunday. Week number represents the weeks in the months.

I have done the following functions:
My code for these functions are below.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from datetime import date

def week(week_num, start_day, days_in_month):
    week_string = ""

    if week_num == 1:
        if start_day == 1:
            week_string = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
        elif start_day == 2: 
            week_string = "  1 2 3 4 5 6"
        elif start_day == 3:
            week_string = "    1 2 3 4 5"
        elif start_day == 4:
            week_string = "      1 2 3 4"
        elif start_day == 5:
            week_string = "        1 2 3"
        elif start_day == 6:
            week_string = "          1 2"
        elif start_day == 7:
            week_string = "            1"

    elif week_num == 2:
        if start_day == 1:
            week_string = "8 9 10 11 12 13 14"
        elif start_day == 2: 
            week_string = "7 8 9 10 11 12 13"
        elif start_day == 3:
            week_string = "6 7 8 9 10 11 12"
        elif start_day == 4:
        #carry on in the above way, but this doesn't seem efficient

    return week_string

def main():
    month_name = input("Enter month:\n")
    year = eval(input("Enter year:\n"))


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do the function? I need to return a string value

Another idea I had:

```
def week(week_num, start_day, days_in_month):
    week_string = ""
    if week_num == 1:
        week_string = ""
        day = start_day

        for i in range(1, 8 -start_day+1):
            week_string = week_string + str(i) + " "
        week_string = "{0:<20}".format(week_string)
    return week_string
```

An example of the input and output of this function:

```
week(1, 3, 30)
```

returns the string

```
' 1 2 3 4 5'
```

```
week(2, 3, 30)
```

returns the string

```
' 6 7 8 9 10 11 12’
```

Comment: are you allowed to use `datetime` module? what do you have to do "by hand"?

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: could you clarify a bit more what you want to achieve? By week number you mean number in the month or number in the year? Some example would be great.

Comment: Week number means number of week in month. Some examples: week(1, 3, 30) returns the string ' 1 2 3 4 5'
week(2, 3, 30) returns the string ' 6 7 8 9 10 11 12’

Comment: You are allowed to use the datetime module. But it would be better to do it by hand. Either is fine

Answer (score 0):

edit: you heavily altered your question, I'll update my response once I'll understand what you need

`datetime` and `calendar` modules should supply you with all you need

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

# is leapyear
calendar.isleap(2020) # True

# just add +1 if you need it in the format that you want
datetime.strptime('25.2.2020', '%d.%m.%Y').weekday() # = 1 = Tuesday

# from name to month number
datetime.strptime('february', '%B').month # = 2

# days in month and weekday of starting month
# with the starting weekday you can easily calculate the number of weeks
calendar.monthrange(2020,2) # = (5, 29), 5=saturday, 29 days in month
```

Some general remarks to your code:

1. You can use `'January'.upper()` to convert it to `'JANUARY'` and only need to check `month_name=='JANUARY'` and save you the redundant comparison
2. You can use `if month_num in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:` to make it more readable

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can you figure out the rest that you need by the examples I gave?